# Python cannot find the executed function after exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-exec

I cannot find the executed function even after the excution.

This is the function:

```
# function illustrating how exec() functions.
def exec_code():
    LOC = """ 
def factorial(num): 
    fact=1 
    for i in range(1,num+1): 
        fact = fact*i 
    return fact 
print(factorial(5)) 
"""
    exec(LOC) 
    print(factorial)

# Driver Code 
exec_code()
```

However, this yields an error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d403750cbbfb> in <module>
     13 
     14 # Driver Code
---> 15 exec_code()

<ipython-input-10-d403750cbbfb> in exec_code()
     10 """
     11     exec(LOC)
---> 12     print(factorial)
     13 
     14 # Driver Code

NameError: name 'factorial' is not defined
```

I really would like to execute a string function as the above pattern. Does anyone know how to solve it? If exec is not recomanded, are there any other solutions?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. [Here's one I wrote](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/4ae79ecd7f28f066e3ae6671c9f48fc1). You could use it if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for `exec(object[, globals[, locals]])`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

> Note The default locals act as described for function locals() below:
>   modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be
>   attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see
>   effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns.

---

Therefore, you need to pass your own locals dict in as globals and locals:

```
mylocals = {}
exec(your_code, mylocals, mylocals)
```

Then you can call it through the mylocals:

```
print(mylocals['factorial']())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give globals() to the exec call to make it add the function to the current module:

```
exec(LOC,globals())
```